Why can't I set variable name in Logic app(Cannot edit in read-only editor)
I want to create a simple Logic APP in Azure Portal. But I cannot set a variable!
It says "Cannot edit in read-only editor"

I went to Code View because I couldn't type the variable name under Parameters.
How to fix this?

You need to use the Initialize variable operation first (once) before you can use the Set variable, Increment variable, Decrement variable, Append to variable, etc. operations (as many times as needed). You'll be able to select the initialized variables in the Name dropdown box in those operations.


To set a variable first, you need to initialize it and then you can set a variable like below:

Then you can set like this:

And you cannot change code like that as, Its Just View , you cannot change the values there.
To change the values or set the value using code you can use code section in workflow, where you can change the value or set it.

